# Surface integration w.r.t Hausdorff measure

Tags: integration, hausdorff-measure

I am reading at Evans' book *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions, Revised Edition, p. 165* and I can't see how one gets the transition from the first dotted () integral to the second one --

We have
[image: Hausdorff surface measure]

-- here $Df$ is just the gradient of $f$ and $d H^{n - 1}$ is the Hausdorff surface measure.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$w\in \partial B(z,ts)$, so $|w-z|=ts$ and hence
$$
\frac{s^p}{t^{n-1}}=s^{n+p-1}|w-z|^{1-n}.
$$
You can also check Lemma 2.33 in my [Lecture notes](https://sites.pitt.edu/%7Ehajlasz/Notatki/Cortona%20Lectures.pdf), where the proof of the result you are studying is presented in a slightly different way.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the extra material!